# How to download and run iOS simulator on PC Windows

Tags: ios, windows, ios-simulator

I want to try testing my app on iOS simulator on my computer PC Windows. Have anyone tried to do that before?

Answer (score 1):

We also had that problem. We found out, Apple things (as your simulation) can only be done on Apple computers. So if you want to have an IOS simulator you have this three options

- Buy a mac (expensive)
- Hackintosh or similar thing (a bit hard, because you need to keep your mac updated)
- Use a cloud provider, which supports this (here I have no experience)

Comment: Okay I see. I assume there may be a way to run iOS on PC via Mac OS VMware installed on Windows but I don't have any clue on how to do that.

Comment: Yes, that's the second option. there are some disadvantages. slow speed and not to good options to update are just two of them...

Comment: Ah yes. But if we want fast speed, then more ram is needed

Comment: It's not only ram. It's cpu too and i think graphical memory is a point too...

Comment: Yes sure. How about i7 at least 3GHz and nvidia 2gb too?

Comment: I don't know. I've never tried it. We ended up buying a mac

Comment: You can use appetize.io to test your app online.